# Mapping a BSON MongoDB document to a MyClass.class object?

Tags: java, mongodb, netbeans, pojo

Have a nice day everyone!

I'm trying to understand MongoDB in the JAVA. I'm trying to map the MongoDB Document object to my own java object.

> **My MongoDB Document structure**:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "$oid" : "5f2d37f1cdf2f93d01fd5f9a"
    },
    "Person_ID" : {
        "$numberInt" : "3"
    }, "Name" : "John", "Lastname" : "Doe"
}
```

> **MyClass.class model:**

```
public class MyClass {
    String oid;
    int Person_ID;
    int numberInt;
    String Name, Lastname;

   //empty constructor
   public MyClass() {}

   // Setters and Getters
}
```

> **Using JAVA I try:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(
        "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster.lt8te.mongodb.net/dbProject? 
          retryWrites=true&w=majority"); 
   
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(uri);            
    MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("dbProject");
    MongoCollection<Document> coll = db.getCollection("myCollection");
    Document doc = (Document) coll.find().first();
    
    System.out.println(doc.toJson());
    
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    MongoObject mongoObj = gson.fromJson(doc.toJson(), MyClass.class);
}
```

> **I'm getting an error:**
> *Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 10 path $._id*

I think my MyClass model not matches the Document mongoDB model.
I'm not very sure where I have a mistake. Or what to edit?
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last line you are trying to map a JSON to your MyClass java object. For that to work JSON structure has to match with your java class. Assuming the JSON result from `doc.toJson()` will look like your Mongo document that you have shown, implement your class as below. The idea is your JSON documents data type should match with your class, For example `Person_ID` in your JSON is an Object which has three attribute in it so in your java class there should be a variable with name Person_ID which will of a another Class type with  three attribute.

```
public class MyClass {
    ID _id;
    Person Person_ID;

   //empty constructor
   public MyClass() {}

   // Setters and Getters


}

Class ID{
   public String oid;
   //Getter setter
}

Class Person {
    int numberInt;
    String Name;
    String Lastname;

//Getter setter
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your advice helped me.
In the end, the structure of the document was different. But I already know how to do it. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 4):

So after a few hours of studying. And with the help of StackOverFlow, I can present a solution here that can help others. Let's grasp the structure of the BSON Document, which I gave here as an example.

> **Here:**

```
{
   "_id" : {
       "$oid" : "5f2d37f1cdf2f93d01fd5f9a"
   },
   "Person_ID" : {
       "$numberInt" : "3"
   }, "Name" : "John", "Lastname" : "Doe"
```

}

> *MongoDB requires that you have an '_id' field for all documents. If you don't provide one the driver will assign a ObjectId with a generated value.*

Now you need to create an object model of this JSON.
Like this: (It is important to maintain the order of the fields.)

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

public class ModelMongo 
{
    ObjectId _id;
    int Person_ID;
    String Name;
    String Lastname;

    public ModelMongo(ObjectId id, int Person_ID, String Name, String Lastname) 
    }
        this._id = id;
        this.Person_ID = Person_ID;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Lastname = Lastname;
    {

      // Setter and Getter ...      
}
```

Assuming you have the same document structure as in the example above and you want to map a domain mongo document to your own java class:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
}
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(uri);            
    MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("dbProject");
    MongoCollection<org.bson.Document> coll = db.getCollection("myCollection");
    Document doc = (Document) coll.find().first();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ModelMongo model = gson.fromJson(doc.toJson(), ModelMongo.class);  

    /***                                                ****
    * Now in the variable model is a Document from MongoDB *
    * Access to variables of that Object possible through  *
    * its Getter methods.                              ****/
{
```

> *Dependency:*

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/bson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: To simplify it looks like you can have a parameterless constructor instead and rely on your public getters and setters.